# Form fechando sem close()

Tags: c#, winforms

Caros amigos, tenho um form bem simples que está fechando após clicar OK no MessageBox. Já revisei tudo, comparei com outros forms que tenho e não encontrei a solução. Se alguem puder me dar uma ajuda, agraço.

```
namespace menu
{
    public partial class frmFinanceiroDocumentosVencidosGrid : Form
    {
        public frmFinanceiroDocumentosVencidosGrid()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        public int codigo { get; set; }


        private void frmFinanceiroDocumentosVencidosGrid_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ClienteBLL.verificaParcelasVencidas(codigo);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }


        private void btnVisualizar_documento_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                int codigo = (int)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;
                Financeiro fin = FinanceiroBLL.pesquisaFinanceiroCodigo(codigo);
                if (fin.nota_fiscal_id != null)
                {
                    int nota_codigo = (int)fin.nota_fiscal_id;
                    using (frmNotaFiscalVisualizar ver = new frmNotaFiscalVisualizar())
                    {
                        ver.codigo = nota_codigo;
                        ver.ShowDialog();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Não há notas fiscais vinculadas à este documento.");
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnFechar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é código do formulário `frmNotaFiscalVisualizar`?

Comment: O que está chamando esse `Form`?

Answer (score 2):

Cheque qual o valor da propriedade `DialogResult` do botão, ela deve ter como valor  `DialogResult.None`.

Um outro detalhe, o formulário tem duas propriedades `AcceptButton` e `CancelButton` verifique se o botão a qual você está clicando não está selecionado nestas propriedades.

Answer (score 0):

pode ser que esteja acontecendo algum erro ou exception não tratada, vc pode experimentar colocar um try / catch para testar

```
private void btnVisualizar_documento_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            int codigo = (int)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;
            Financeiro fin = FinanceiroBLL.pesquisaFinanceiroCodigo(codigo);
            if (fin.nota_fiscal_id != null)
            {
                int nota_codigo = (int)fin.nota_fiscal_id;
                using (frmNotaFiscalVisualizar ver = new frmNotaFiscalVisualizar())
                {
                    ver.codigo = nota_codigo;
                    ver.ShowDialog();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Não há notas fiscais vinculadas à este documento.");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```